# Use cases for hstore vs json datatypes in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

In Postgresql, the hstore and json datatypes seem to have very similar use cases. When would you choose to use one vs. the other? Initial thoughts:

- You can nest with json; you can't with hstore
- Functions for parsing json won't be available until 9.3

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: read [here](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.2#JSON_datatype), but even if it was validity checking alone, that is a 'good thing'

Comment: sorry! copied and pasted the wrong thing

Comment: I think the last comment (it's depesz's) describes the answer very well here: http://www.depesz.com/2013/03/30/waiting-for-9-3-add-new-json-processing-functions-and-parser-api/

Comment: question seems pretty clear to me @dezso

Comment: @ckarbass Thanks for the input.  If you check the question history, the version that triggered my comment was very different from the present one.

Comment: @dezso cool. makes sense.

Answer (score 8):

Taken from http://www.depesz.com/2013/03/30/waiting-for-9-3-add-new-json-processing-functions-and-parser-api/ per dezso's comment:

> Given current limitations for both datatypes, I would say that they
>   should be used in different scenarios:
>
> if you want indexable searches, and you’re fine with “no-nesting”
>   limitation: use hstore. if you need nested, complicated structures,
>   and don’t care about indexing – use json. and if you need the best
>   from both world – you’ll have to wait to see what, and when, the
>   future will bring.

Comment: What about in 9.3?

Comment: jsonb support indexing, in version 12.